# Identify-form is mostly hidden

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 3.0 I try to identify features by user-form (.ui). The opening form-window is very small and hides nearly every content of the form. It has to be expanded every time manually by cursor to the full form size to see all contents of the form. 
What settings have to be changed that the form opens in full-size ?

[image]

Comment: is the form created with qt designer? if so can you add a minium size constraint?

Comment: Yes. Opend the with 2.x qt-designer created form with the 3.0 qt designer. Saved it with new filename. Changed the filename in layersettings. Same behaviour